UI not updating after items deleted from list
I have a React Native Typescript app, which will show numerous video players on the screen similar to Instagram or other apps. I get a list of data from a REST API, and as the user scrolls, the app will populate 5 items (video players) of that data. I want to restrict around 25 results in the ScrollView at a time. So as the limit of 25 is reached, it should delete the first 5 items and append 5 new items. I have to do this because my screen becomes very slow and laggy with the increasing number of video players. The code currently does not update the UI:
import { Component, ReactNode } from "react";

import { IOScrollView } from "react-native-intersection-observer";

// More imports here



export const players_control: PlayersControl = {
    EACH_SET: 5,
    MAX_LIMIT: 25
};

// Props definition

interface State {
    contents: Content[];
};

export default class ReelsPage extends Component<Props, State> {

    state: State;

    private contents: Content[] = [];

    private PlayingContainers: PlayingContainer[] = [];

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { contents: [] };
    }

    private onScroll(): void {
        // Manually check when the last `PlayingContainers` appear in screen and fire `onScrollReachedEnd`
    }

    private get(): void {
        // Get total results of around 100+ from REST API
    }



    private onScrollReachedEnd(): void {
        if (contains(this.contents)) {
            const ti: Content[] = this.contents.slice(0, players_control.EACH_SET); // Get 5 each time
            this.contents = this.contents.slice(players_control.EACH_SET);
            if (contains(ti)) {
                this.setState((prevState: State) => {
                    const c: Content[] = [ ...prevState.contents, ...ti ]; // Add 5 new items
                    if (c.length >= players_control.MAX_LIMIT) {
                        // Delete first 5 items
                        c = c.slice(players_control.EACH_SET);
                    }
                    return { contents: c, ... /* Set few other values as well */ };
                }, (): void => {
                    this.nextStep();
                });
            }
        } else this.get();
    }


    render(): ReactNode {

        return <>
            <IOScrollView
                onScroll={(e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>): void => {
                    this.onScroll();
                }}
                // Other stuff
            >
                <View style={styles["main-container"]}>
                    {this.state.contents.map((c: Content, i: number): ReactNode => <Fragment key={i}>

                        {/* Custom screen Native Context here */}
                        <AppContextContainer.Provider value={this.state.appcontext}>
                            <PlayingContainer
                                ref={(e: PlayingContainer): void => {
                                    this.PlayingContainers[i] = e;
                                }}
                                // Lots of other video player stuff events and information here
                            />
                        </AppContextContainer.Provider>
                    </Fragment>)}
                </View>
            </IOScrollView>
        </>;
    }
}


Give us the whole component bb

@johnhaup I have added more code of my component. This component is very large and has numerous event listeners so I have not included code for it.
